# A way to pass in a constant list into a cmake macro?

Tags: cmake

I have a CMake macro like so:

```
macro( foo a b )
  list( FIND b ${a} is_found )
endmacro()
```

And I try to call it like so:

```
foo( "test" foo;bar;test )
```

This doesn't work. Also this does not work:

```
foo( "test" "foo;bar;test" )
```

In all cases I get `is_found` equal to `-1`, when in fact it should have been found. How can I pass in a list on-the-fly like I want to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because parameters of a macro and special values such as `ARGN` are not variables in the usual CMake sense. They are string replacements much like the c preprocessor would do with a macro.

You can copy input arguments to the variable and next pass that variable to list find:

```
macro( foo a )
  set( b "${ARGN}" )
  list( FIND b "${a}" is_found )
endmacro()
```

As result all the following variants work:

```
foo(test foo bar test foo )
foo("test" foo bar test foo )
foo(test foo;bar;test;foo )
foo("test" foo;bar;test;foo )
foo(test "foo;bar;test;foo" )
foo("test" "foo;bar;test;foo" )
```

---

Update, more generic version - search in several lists separated by "NEXTLIST" word:

```
macro( foo a )
  set( is_found )
  set( foo_current_list )
  foreach( arg ${ARGN} )
    if( arg STREQUAL "NEXTLIST" )
      list( FIND foo_current_list "${a}" foo_is_found )
      list( APPEND is_found ${foo_is_found} )
      set( foo_current_list )
    else()
      list( APPEND foo_current_list ${arg} )
    endif()
  endforeach()
  list( FIND foo_current_list "${a}" foo_is_found )
  list( APPEND is_found ${foo_is_found} )
  unset( foo_is_found )
  unset( foo_current_list )
endmacro()

foo (test bar bar bar NEXTLIST foo test NEXTLIST test test x test)
message( "${is_found}" ) #-1;1;0
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I had forgotten about ARGN. What about another scenario where you have 2 lists you want to pass into 'foo'?

Comment: If you want to pass several lists then you need to separate them in some way. You can introduce a named argument for each list but in this case you can't simple past list of space-separated values to the macro. Or similar to many cmake commands you can use a special separator to distinguish your arguments. I've updated the answer with a generic version which is able to search in multiple lists.